# How to set new players into a team?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I haven't played Minecraft for a while now, and I've forgotten an awful lot about commands blocks, redstone, and scoreboards as such. So I have two questions:

1. If a new player joins the game, how can I set them into a team, and then give them 1 xp?
2. If a player is in a team, and has 1 xp, how would I teleport them to a specific location?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: How will you be determining which team to place that player on? You can add a player to a team with `/scoreboard teams join Team @p`, which will add the nearest player to the team called "Team", but it doesn't really make much sense to do unless there's some method to separate them, otherwise why bother using the team feature?

Comment: Should all players be added onto a team, or should some players not have one? By "If a player is in a team", do you mean a specific team or just any team?

Comment: There are also easy ways to scramble teams around a map but it's hard to say the best way to do a thing if we're not entirely sure what it is you're trying to do

Comment: @colorfusion It's a specific team, 
I'm making a server with ranks...

Comment: Should every player have a team, or do you need some players to not be on any team at all?

Comment: @colorfusion Every player will be in teams...

Answer (score 1):

> 1: If a new player joins, how can i set them into a team and give them, 1 xp?

Have the following commands running, in this order, on a clock:

```
/xp 1l @a[team=]
/scoreboard teams join <NewPlayerTeamName> @a[team=]
```

As you've said every player should be in a team, only newly joined players will have no team (`team=`). After receiving 1l, they'll be put onto `<NewPlayerTeamName>` (replace with an existing team).

---

> 2: If a player is in a team, and has 1 xp, how do i teleport them to a certain place?

```
/tp @a[team=<TeamName>,lm=1] X Y Z
```

The `team=` selector finds people on `<TeamName>` (replace with an existing team) with at least one EXP level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on question 2... I already figured out #1, thanks to this post:
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263241/how-to-assign-players-in-mc-to-a-scoreboard-team-automatically-when-they-join?rq=1

Comment: All though, i just found this when someone joined on the command block:
[23:03:30] Unknown command. Try /help for a list of commands
I had this command; /tp @a[team=Botchers,lm=1] 1101 99 889